# How to have a matrix of X line with different vectors for each line?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have unknown vector which are produced by a loop. Every time one is created, I want to add it to a matrix.

For example, let's say I have my variable containing them being `p`.

On first turn I have vector `[ 1 2 3 ]`

then I want `p` to be

```
[ 1 2 3 ]
```

then I produce vector `[ 4 4 5 6 6 ]`

Then I want be to contains

```
[ 1 2 3 ]
[ 4 4 5 6 6 ]
```

So I can do something like `p(1)` to access first vector, and `p(2)` for second.

What is the closest representation I could use?

Comment: You need a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), not a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix needs to be rectangular, since MATLAB doesn't like Swiss cheese. The closest you can get to that representation is cells:

```
p{1} = [1 2 3];
p{2} = [ 4 4 5 6 6 ];
```

Cells are a tad more cumbersome to work with than matrices, due to their allowance of irregular shaped matrices and even non-uniform datatypes across their elements, but at least they do what you want.

The other option would be zero padding I'd say:

```
p = [1 2 3];
newvec = [ 4 4 5 6 6 ];
if length(newvec)>length(p)
    p = [p zeros(size(newvec)-size(p))];
    else
        newvec = [newvec zeros(size(p)-size(newvec))];
end
```

Comment: And you should also preallocate `p` with the number of cells to be filed.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make this clear for the OP, in case he did not pay attention for that.